# Select event of p:timeline of Primefaces 6 does not trigger bean method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, timeline

I have this xhtml in which i have a p:timeline... i want to when i select an object (training pLan), show a modal dialog with the details. But i can´t get the select event to trigger... the method never gets called!

Here is my xhtml code

```
<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
<legend class="scheduler-border">#{msg['tp_list']}</legend>
<p:timeline id="timeline" value="#{nav.model}" height="450px" selectable="#{nav.selectable}" zoomable="# {nav.zoomable}" moveable="#{nav.moveable}" stackEvents="#{nav.stackEvents}" axisOnTop="#{nav.axisOnTop}" eventStyle="#{nav.eventStyle}" showCurrentTime="#{nav.showCurrentTime}" showNavigation="#{nav.showNavigation}">

<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{nav.onSelect}" />
</p:timeline>
</fieldset>
```

here is my bean:

```
@Named("nav")
@ViewScoped

private TimelineModel model;

private boolean selectable = true;
private boolean zoomable = true;
private boolean moveable = true;
private boolean stackEvents = true;
private String eventStyle = "box";
private boolean axisOnTop;
private boolean showCurrentTime = true;
private boolean showNavigation = false;

.
.
.
@PostConstruct
protected void initialize() {
LOGGER.info("In post-Construct INITIALIZE!");

model = new TimelineModel();
allPlans = tPlanService.getAllTPlan();

for (TrainingPlan tp : allPlans) {
LOGGER.info("IN FOR: " + tp.getEndDate());
model.add(new TimelineEvent(tp.getName(), tp.getStartDate(), tp.getEndDate()));
}

}

public void onSelect(TimelineSelectEvent e) {
LOGGER.info("In onSelect of NAV");
TimelineEvent timelineEvent = e.getTimelineEvent();

facesMessageBox.infoMessage("Selected event:", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
```

this method (onSelect) is never called by the ajax! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showcase example did not work for me too. But adding the *process* attribute with the enclosing form as value to *ajax* tag worked for me:

```xml
<h:form id="form">
  ...
  <p:ajax
    event="select"
    listener="#{nav.onSelect}"
    process=":form"
  />
  ...
</h:form>
```

Please note: adding *@this* or the timeline identifier did not work too!

Comment: Ok! thank you! this did the trick! But i had to "broke" my form in to two! because i was getting some data from DB to show in a modal! But worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Had the same issue. Issue raised and will be fixed in 6.2 https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2425 : Timeline clientId generation broken

Comment: When I try this I get "Cannot find component for expression ":form"" as a javascript error

Comment: @Momus Sounds like your enclosing forms id is not "form". Just replace the process attribute value of the ajax behavior with your forms id. By the way, this is not a javascript error but a simple runtime exception thrown by primefaces.

Comment: @irieill my timeline does not even show, am using primefaces 8.0.0. Where do i add the @ this and also what is the timeline identifier and how can i use it?

Comment: @Afroid1000 I recommend to create a separate question with a detailed description and code example of your problem.

Comment: @irieill..i agree. Thanks.